# How to retrieve string from NSData stored in sqlite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nsstring, nsdata

**Note:**

1. I have stored `NSData` in local database.
2. I want to use it back from local database. But as it is stored in
   local database as text ,facing issue in converting back it into
   `NSData`.
3. strDbData is object of type `NSString` here.

I have one `NSData` stored in local database like  `<a3829c97 3b1efacb c7680f7e 7e7a95a2>`

Now I want to retrive it back, so I am doing as mentioned below but I am receiving error.

1)  First way

```
NSData *myData = (NSData*)strDbData;
NSLog(@"%@",[myData class]);
```

Error : `-[__NSCFString AES256DecryptWithKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddcd9c0`

2) Second way

```
NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:(NSData*)strDbData];
```

Error: `-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dd61a40`

So how do I convert `NSData` sotred in local database as 'text' back into `NSData` ?

**EDIT**

```
strDbData = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
```

**EDIT 2** Storing NSData in database

```
-(BOOL)updateSingleRow:(NSData*)myData 
{
    @try
    {
        BOOL success = NO;
        sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
        const char *stmt = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE ABC SET XYZ = '%@' WHERE ID = 1 ",myData] UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open([databaseFilePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if(sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE )
                {
                    NSLog( @"updateSingleRow Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
                }
                else if (sqlite3_total_changes(database)>0)
                {
                    success = YES;
                }
                else if (sqlite3_total_changes(database)==0)
                {
                    NSLog(@"No Updates : %@" , query);
                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
        return success;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        TRACE_ERROR(@"updateSingleRow", exception.name, exception.description);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is type of strDbData ? Is it NSString ?

Comment: If you have NSData in the database, where does the **NSString** `strDbData` come from?

Comment: yes where does that string come from?

Comment: @MartinR I am storing <a3829c97 3b1efacb c7680f7e 7e7a95a2> in database and fetching back and storing in strDbData when I want to use

Comment: Please show the code: How is strDbData created?

Comment: @MartinR I have updated in question

Comment: I have data -> which gets saved as text and then fetching back text as string -> want to use as NSData. But when i use it i get above error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the SQLite column contains binary data, you should read it back via

```
const void *bytes = sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 6);
int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 6);
NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:length];
```

instead of reading it into a string.

To store binary data, use a "prepared statement". (I did not test this code, I hope that
it is correct!)

```
const char *stmt = "UPDATE ABC SET XYZ = ? WHERE ID = 1";
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [myData bytes], [myData length], NULL);
    // ...
```

Comment: the way you show is correct. I appreciate for this.  but why when i print myData while fetching it is printing <3c613338 32396339 37203362 31656661 63622063 37363830 66376520 37653761 39356132 3e>. Why this is so.? Also when i print class of it, it shows NSConcreteData instead NSData

Comment: @Bhargavi: That means that you have stored the **string** "<a3829c97 3b1efacb c7680f7e 7e7a95a2>" in your database and not binary data. So you have another problem in your code where you save the data. Perhaps you can show that code (I already guess where the problem is :-)

Comment: I have edited in question again .please suggest me what I am doing wrong

Comment: one more question what should be data type of field in sqlite db for storing NSData binary or blob ?

Comment: @Bhargavi: I have updated the answer, I hope that helps. - Probably BLOB, but I am not 100% sure, please try it yourself.

Comment: @Bhargavi: Did you make some progress with this problem? Did my answer help?

Comment: I will work on that issue afterwards and will implement this way surely. I will tell you which one helped me for sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try load data as `dataWithContentsOfFile:`, or `initWithBytes:length:`, or some else from `NSData` methods.

Some example:

```
void* bytedata = [self getByteDataByParam:param];

NSData* loadedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:byteData length:length];
```

Comment: I have data in database not in file

Comment: I'm sorry, ok, but `NSData` have couple of methods to create NSData from some else source: bytes, file, etc., Did you try `initWithBytes:length:` or some else?

Answer (score -1):

Your Database Field should of type Blob instead of String
that will solve the problem